# Debugging on iOS without a paid developer membership (3.x)

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging

I currently have it set up for Xcode to Build & Go onto my iPod using this: http://il.youtube.com/watch?v=CHOVdi-kPV0 (A script to tell Xcode that it doesn't need to codesign). This works, except when the app launches, it closes instantly and Xcode says it failed to launch. You can manually reopen the application and it works 100% after. The problem is I need to be able to build & go through Xcode, and have the application stay open so I can debug on the device. Does anyone have a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I followed this guide and it worked for me: http://www.alexwhittemore.com/?p=354

Comment: Yeah, I used that guide too (Well, a script based off it). It doesn't allow me to debug on device though, nor does it for my friend. Are you able to debug with this guide?

Comment: Actually, I wasn't adding a custom build phase to my project, thank you!